# How does switch statement work?

Tags: c, switch-statement

How are statements that come before any `case` labelled statement in a `switch-case` block treated.
Please explain the behavior of the following programs

prog1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  switch(1)
  {   
    int i=0; 
    case 1:printf("%d",i);         
  }
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Output: garbage value.

prog2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  switch(1)
  {  
    printf("Inside Switch");  
    case 1:printf("Case 1\n");      
  }
  printf("Outside Switch");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

Case 1

Outside Switch.

The statements before a case labelled statement seem unreachable according to program 2 but then why don't i get an error for an undeclared variable `i` in the first program (only a warning).

Would be really helpful if someone could explain in detail that how the `switch` statement is treated internally.

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds like homework. If so, add the `homework` tag and show your own work so far.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is not homework.I came across this while taking the C quiz on gild and i am curious to know.

Comment: A `switch` statement is basically syntactic sugar for a jump table with `goto`s.

Comment: Have you tried compiling the use of an undeclared variable outside a switch scope with the same compiler? What does it output? Maybe it depends on the warning/error settings of your compiler? And here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson5.html

Comment: @TheNail I did try that. But it gave an error message.

Comment: Ah so the warning is not for an undeclared variable, just for being uninitialized. I see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is best explained by quotations from the c standard. 
I am quoting the relevant parts from the standard which apply to your question here.

**6.8.4.2 The switch statement**

**Para 4:**

> A `switch` statement causes control to jump to, into, or past the statement that is the
>   `switch` body, depending on the value of a controlling expression, and on the presence of a
>   `default` label and the values of any `case` labels on or in the switch body......

**Para 2:**

> If a `switch` statement has an associated `case` or `default` label within the scope of an
>   identifier with a variably modified type, the entire switch statement shall be within the
>   scope of that identifier.<sup>154)</sup>

**FootNote:**

> <sup>154)</sup> That is, the declaration either precedes the switch statement, or it follows the last `case` or `default` label associated with the `switch` that is in the block containing the declaration.

**Para 7:**
EXAMPLE In the artificial program fragment

```
switch (expr)
{
    int i = 4;
    f(i);
    case 0:
       i = 17;
       /* falls through into default code */
    default:
       printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

> the object whose identifier is `i` exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but is never initialized, and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, **the call to the `printf` function will access an indeterminate value. Similarly, the call to the function `f` cannot be reached**.

---

The above mentioned applies to both of the code examples in the Question.
`Example 1`, `i` has an **Indeterminate** value since it was never initialized & hence prints garbage, While in
`Example 2`, `printf` call is not reached because the control jumps to the matching `case` label.

Comment: thanks for this and others you have answered for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1. I have also a small writeup on how they get implemented by compiler if you are interested, see [here](http://lazarenko.me/2013/01/13/switch-statement-machine-code/).

Answer (score 5):

Basically, a switch acts like a goto to the appropriate label -- intervening statements aren't executed. Variable definitions (which actually happen at compile time) do happen, but if they contain initialization, that's skipped too.

Answer (score 2):

**Never write statements in switch which are not part of any case or default because they won't be executed.**

NOTE: declaration can be written there but not statement (int i; is declaration but int i = 10; is declaration + assignment = statement so assignment will not be perform there..!)

```
switch(a)
{
printf("This will never print"); // this will never executed
case 1:
        printf(" 1");
break;
 
default :
break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and answer.