# How does switch behave as a goto?

Tags: c, switch-statement, goto

I was trying to understand the working of `switch` in C, and after browsing through some of the answers on SO, I fumbled upon the following piece of answer on SO :-

> Basically, a switch acts like a goto to the appropriate label -- intervening statements aren't executed. Variable definitions (which actually happen at compile time) do happen, but if they contain initialization, that's skipped too.

[How does switch statement work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408984/how-does-switch-statement-work)

Can anybody please explain the meaning of this statement or provide some more insight into the working of `switch`.
`

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulties with from the link you posted? The accepted answer along with the statement you have highlighted seem clear enough.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of how to use it? For an explanation how it's implemented internally? For philosophical ruminations on its similarity to goto statements?

Comment: I am  not able to understand how this particular answers that problem in the link.

Comment: A code example could be really useful to demonstrate the truth of this statement.

Comment: @ps06756, There are code examples in the other answers to the post that you linked.

Comment: @merlin2011 There are code examples for other answers. I am just looking for a code snippet demonstrating this answer. I am unable to think of it myself.

Comment: @ps06756, Very well, I will write a short example.

Comment: @ps06756, I have shown you two code samples, one with `goto` and one with `switch`. In both cases, variable definition happens, but variable initialization is skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a `switch` statement, directly copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409145/391161).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int expr = 1;
    switch (expr)
    {
        int i = 4;
        f(i);
        case 0:
        i = 17;
        /* falls through into default code */
        default:
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Here is an equivalent code sample, written with `goto`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int expr = 1;
    if (expr == 0) goto label0;
    else goto label1;

    int i = 4;
    f(i);
    label0:
    i = 17;

    label1:
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Observe that, in both cases, when `expr` is initialized to `1`, the initialization statement `int i = 4` is **not executed**, so `i` is not initialized. However, `i` is defined, just as the quote in the question mentions.

Answer (score 1):

Without switch:

```
  if(1 == x)
     goto LABEL_A;
  else if(2 == x)
     goto LABEL_B;
  else if(10 == x)
     goto LABEL_C;
  else
     goto LABEL_D;

LABEL_A:
  /* Do A */;
  goto BREAK;

LABEL_B:
  /* Do B */;
  goto BREAK;

LABEL_C:
  /* Do C */;
  goto BREAK;

LABEL_D:
  /* Do D */;
  goto BREAK;

BREAK:
```

With switch:

```
switch(x)
  {
  case 1:
     /* Do A */;
     break;

  case 2:
     /* Do B */;
     break;

  case 10:
     /* Do C */;
     break;

  default:
     /* Do D */;
     break;
  }
```