# Non-traditional uses of switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

Recently I found out that the body of a switch can be any statement (C99 6.8.4). The idea was first suggested to me by this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9220598/515212

So one can have switch statements like

```
void f(int n)
{
    switch (n)
    case 0:
        printf("zero\n");
}
```

or even put `if`s, `while`s, etc.

```
void f(int n)
{
    switch (n) 
    if (1)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("zero\n");
    }
    else
        while (--n)
        {
            default:
                printf("non-zero\n");
        }
}
```

Just out of interest, I was wondering whether this syntax has some usage or is just an artifact of how the switch statement is defined in the standard?

Comment: The indentation and the lack of braces in your code is too confusing.

Comment: @iharob The fact that one can skip the braces is exactly the point of the question.

Comment: I mean the `if` and `else while` look very disturbing to me.

Comment: You should be careful when modifying the switch var from inside a case statement.  I'm not saying that it should never be done, (it's one way of implementing a state-machine), but decrementing it in a loop is likely to be very confusing!

Comment: @iharob That's what I thought too. But apparently this is permitted by the standard.

Comment: @MartinJames What's your point? Did you read what I am asking?

Comment: Always try to bear in mind that someone may need to maintain or enhance your code one day.  On the off-chance that it's youself, you should strive to keep code 'cleverness' down and code clarity up!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101413/discussion-between-martinkunev-and-martin-james).

Comment: Chat?  Why?  It has a usage and, IMHO, the usage as you posted is a bad idea.  That's it, really.

Comment: @MartinJames I KNOW it's a bad idea. I'm not proposing usage. If you read my question, you'll see I'm asking why is this allowed and is there usage.

Comment: Why would it not be allowed?  ' If you read my question' - you think that there is some chance I have not?  Maybe I'm missing the import of your question somehow.  Yes, it's permitted,  No, it's not unusual.  No, it should not be misused to obfuscate program flow as you described in your question.

Comment: @MartinJames "you think that there is some chance I have not?" I don't see why else would you mention code style and explain that this is bad (things I apparently know about since I'm asking why would this be allowed). The point of my question is if there is some reason this is allowed.

Comment: It's allowed because it can be useful, just like high explosives can be useful. The usage you indicated in the question is a less than useful, hence the mention of code style and explanation that that is bad.  If I had not read the question, I would be unable to say that.  I don't understand your issue with what I said earlier or your irritating, insulting 'If you read my question'.

Comment: Duff's device is the first thing that comes to mind.  I've also seen a nice state machine implemented like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few unusual usages of `switch()` and `case` that I was playing around with this evening just to see how far it would stretch when I came across this question. Most of these come from various SO postings and answers.

The most famous unusual example is Duff's Device which is already covered in other answers to this question.

**The basics of `switch()`**

The `switch()` statement has the basic form of:

```
switch (<expression>) <statement>;
```

where

- `<expression>` is an expression that evaluates to an integral value
- `<statement>` is a statement or compound statement with labels

`<statement>` is either a single statement terminated by a semicolon or a series of statements enclosed in curly braces, a compound statement. Optional `case` labels which specify a constant value can be used to act as jump targets if the constant value equals the value of `<expression>` specified in the `switch()`.

The `case` labels are similar to `goto` labels with a similar syntax and the `switch()` statement can be thought of as a computed `goto` statement in which the value of `<expression>` determines to which label within the scope of the `switch()` execution will jump.

The `case` labels must specify an integral constant value or an expression from which the compiler can create an integral constant value. Each value specified in a `case` label must be unique within the scope of the `switch()` or the special label of `default` can be used to specify any value other than the specified `case` label values. The order of the `case` labels does not matter.

The `case` and `default` labels do not need to be specified however `switch(i) return 0;` will not do a `return` since there are no labels to jump to. On the other hand `switch(i) default: return 0;` will always return no matter what the value of the variable `i`.

So the following are good `switch()` statements:

```
switch (i) case 1: case 2: return i;

switch (i) {
case 3:
   i++;
    break;

case 1:
    // FALL THROUGH
case 2:
    return i;

default:
    i -= ((i < 10) ? 2 : 5);
    break;
}

// an enum is an integral type so its possible to use them with switch()
typedef enum { TYPE_1 = 0, TYPE_2, TYPE_3 } MyTypes;

MyTypes jjkk = TYPE_1;
switch (jjkk) {
case TYPE_1: doType1(22); break;
case TYPE_2: doType2(33); break;
}

// you can use #define constants so long as they evaluate to an integral valued constant
// the Preprocessor will do the text substitution for you.
#define JKJK1   1
#define JKJK2   2

switch (i) case JKJK1: case JKJK2: printf("JKJK1 or JKJK2\n");


// following use of logical express should transform logical true/false result
// into an integral value of 1 (true) or 0 (false). Expect a warning about
// this usage though.
switch (i < 4) case 1: i *= 2;   // logical true evaluated as integral value of 1
```

**Examples of `switch()` usage**

The first example uses a `do {} while(0)` so that several of the cases use the same `printf()` statement but the cases prepare case specific data to be used in the output.

Assume that we have a data structure in a point of sale which contains a foreign currency tender, e.g. the customer is at an airport shop in Paris where the Euro is the standard currency but the shop also accepts US dollars and the point of sale does a conversion of US dollars to Euros. In the receipt printing we want to print just Euros if the customer is using Euros and if the customer is using US dollars then we want to print the amount of US dollars, the conversion rate, and the amount of Euros.

We have a struct containing the tender data that looks something like:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char   uchMajorCode;
    unsigned char   uchMinorCode;       // indicates which tender
    long    lTenderAmt;         // amount of tender in Euros
    long    lRate;              // conversion rate
    long    lForeignCurrency;   // amount of the foreign currency
    // .... other data
} ItemTender;
```

In the printing logic we have to determine how to format the receipt line for this tender. And yes I know there are other and more readable ways to do this.

```
switch (pItem->uchMinorCode) {
    char *mnemonic;
case FOREIGN_1: do {
        mnemonic = getMnemonic(TRN_FOREIGN_1);
        break;  // break from do {} while()
case FOREIGN_2:
        mnemonic = getMnemonic(TRN_FOREIGN_2);
        break;  // break from do {} while()
case FOREIGN_3:
        mnemonic = getMnemonic(TRN_FOREIGN_3);
        break;  // break from do {} while()
    } while(0);
    printf ("%s\t%ld  %ld @ %ld\n", mnemonic, pItem->lTenderAmt, pItem->lForeignCurrency, pItem->lRate);
    break;    // break from switch()
case LOCAL:
    // FALL THROUGH
default:
    printf ("%s\t%ld\n", getMnemonic(TRN_LOCAL), pItem->lTenderAmt);
    break;    // break from switch()
}
```

**Note:** Be aware that using a `switch()` to jump into a loop will bypass any loop initialization expression with some loop constructs such as `for()`. The loop conditional check expression will also be bypassed when jumping into the loop body. A similar note applies to an `if` statement should a `case` label be in the body of the `if`.

```
switch (i) {
    default: if (iVal > 3) {  // when i is not equal to 5 then iVal is checked
        case 5: iVal++;       // when i equals 5 then iVal is not checked
    }
}
```

or with a `for()` loop should the `case` label be inside the loop then the initialization is bypassed.

```
switch (i) {
    default: for (iVal= 0; iVal< 4; iVal++) {  // i not equal to 5 so iVal is initialized
    case 5:      doSomething (iVal);   // i equals 5 so iVal is not initialized
             }
        break;
}
```

The next unusual usage is to test for a sequence of values and perform some set of steps for those values. This uses the same data struct above. We could also have more than one line if we used curly braces. Without curly braces the first terminating semicolon also terminates the `switch()`.

```
// in the case of a foreign tender perform the currency conversion
switch (pItem->uchMinorCode)
    case FOREIGN_1: case FOREIGN_2: case FOREIGN_3:
      pItem->lTenderAmt = pItem->lForeignCurrency * pItem->lRate;
```

A third unusual usage is to generate a set of values within a `while()` loop and, depending on the value, do something. This example is somewhat contrived to show syntax possibilities. I haven't seen anything like this in the wild however error check after calling a function and doing a retry based on the error code is a possibility.

```
while ((iVal = f(iVal))) {  // get next value in a sequence and do something with it.
    switch (iVal) {
        int j;        // define temporary variable used below.
    case 1:
        continue;     // continue the while() to get next value
    case 2:
        break;        // break from switch() to do printf() below
    case 0: do {
            j = 17;
            break;    // break from do()
    default:
            j = 12;
            break;    // break from do()
        } while (0);  // bottom of the do(). print follows
        printf("   do while - iVal = %d, j = %d\n", iVal, j);
        break;   // break from switch() to do printf() below
    }
    printf(" while - iVal = %d\n", iVal);
    break;       // break from while() loop
}
```

As a fourth example we use a `switch()` statement for testing various bits. Since a `case` must be an integral value which is computed at compile time we can use constants with bitwise operators if the compiler, and most modern ones will do so, will perform the calculation at compile time.

```
#define VAL_1  0x0001
#define VAL_2  0x0002
#define VAL_3  0x0004
#define VAL_4  0x0008

switch (iBitMask & 0x000f) {
case VAL_1:            // only VAL_1 is set
    printf("  only VAL_1 found\n");
    break;
case VAL_1 | VAL_2:    // both and only both VAL_1 and VAL_2 are set
    printf("  both VAL_1 and VAL_2 found\n");
    break;
case VAL_1 | VAL_3:    // both and only both VAL_1 and VAL_3 are set
    printf("  both VAL_1 and VAL_3 found\n");
    break;
case 0x000f & ~VAL_1:
    printf("  everything except for VAL_1 found\n");
    break;
}
```

**References**

[How does switch statement work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408984/how-does-switch-statement-work)

[Does the C standard explicitly indicate truth value as 0 or 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291681/does-the-c-standard-explicitly-indicate-truth-value-as-0-or-1)

[Using continue in a switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146763/using-continue-in-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the `switch` statement as a code block with labels (case(s) are indeed labels) where the control is passed with a goto statement.

Something like

```
void f(int n)
{
    if ( n == 0 ) goto Label_case_0;
    else goto Label_default;

    {
        if ( 1 )
        {
            Label_case_0:
            printf("zero\n");
        }
        else 
            while (--n)
            {
                Label_default:
                printf("non-zero\n");
            }
    }
}
```

In my opinion it is not a good idea to place case labels inside some other control structures because this makes the code difficult to read and can lead to errors.

Comment: `case(s) are indeed labels` They work in a way like labels, but they are not labels proper. One cannot `goto default;` within a `switch` for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is valid C code.
It origins from assembly where every conditional statement uses if, goto and label jumps.

Implementation of array copy using this feature is called [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

```
void copy(char *from, char *to, int count)
{
    int n = (count + 7) / 8;

    switch(count % 8) {
        case 0: do { *to++ = *from++;
        case 7:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 6:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 5:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 4:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 3:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 2:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 1:      *to++ = *from++;
                   } while(--n > 0);
    }
}
```

When you replace `while` with `if` and `goto`

```
void copy(char *from, char *to, int count)
{
    int n = (count + 7) / 8;

    switch(count % 8) {
        case 0: 
        loop:        *to++ = *from++;
        case 7:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 6:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 5:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 4:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 3:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 2:      *to++ = *from++;
        case 1:      *to++ = *from++;
        if(--n > 0) goto loop;
    }
}
```

Then replace `switch` with `if` and `goto`

```
void copy(char *from, char *to, int count)
{
    int n = (count + 7) / 8;

    if(count%8==7)goto case7;
    if(count%8==6)goto case6;
    if(count%8==5)goto case5;
    if(count%8==4)goto case4;
    if(count%8==3)goto case3;
    if(count%8==2)goto case2;
    if(count%8==1)goto case1;
    if(count%8==0)goto case0; // this can be omitted

    case0:                    // this can be omitted
    loop:        *to++ = *from++;
    case7:       *to++ = *from++;
    case6:       *to++ = *from++;
    case5:       *to++ = *from++;
    case4:       *to++ = *from++;
    case3:       *to++ = *from++;
    case2:       *to++ = *from++;
    case1:       *to++ = *from++;

    if(--n > 0) goto loop;
}
```

Which is functionally (almost) equivalent to

```
void copy(char *from, char *to, int count)
{
    while(--n > 0) { 
        *to++ = *from++;
    }
}
```

It's almost equivalent because in the last implementation loop check is performed 8 times more often, what have impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can look [here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex23.html) for example of unusual usage of switch statement. But don't do this in a real code.
Example from link:

```
int duffs_device(char *from, char *to, int count)
{
    {
        int n = (count + 7) / 8;

        switch(count % 8) {
            case 0: do { *to++ = *from++;
                        case 7: *to++ = *from++;
                        case 6: *to++ = *from++;
                        case 5: *to++ = *from++;
                        case 4: *to++ = *from++;
                        case 3: *to++ = *from++;
                        case 2: *to++ = *from++;
                        case 1: *to++ = *from++;
                    } while(--n > 0);
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

It's called [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device). This function copies char array. It uses the trick called "loop unrolling".

Long loops can be slow because every iteration they need to do additional work like comparisons and variable incremention. So one way to speed them up is to duplicate repeating code. Like its done in example.

But modern compilers can do this better, and using code like this is not recommended, because it only confuse people who read it.